# looking for good clicker application

Tags: automation, click, build-automation

I am looking for a good application that have capability for automating the Windows GUI .

somthing that for exemple record my mouse action and repeat in after that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) includes a macro recorder.

Answer (score 2):

There are several automated UI testing systems will let you do this. [SIKULI](http://sikuli.org/) is one of the best freely available examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio, it's worth checking the Code UI tests that ship with it.
There are various [resources](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/kmcgrath/Introduction-to-Creating-Coded-UI-Tests-with-Visual-Studio-2010) out there to get you stared on that.

Two heavyweight suites that focus on what you are after are [IBM's Rational Robot](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/tester/robot/) & [HP QTP](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software/software-solution.html?compURI=tcm:245-937061). Both come at a high prize, but are very professional and stable - at least that's my experience on them.